# Change NSString to int value?

Tags: objective-c

I am having trouble trying to run this test due to an error on the first line of this code that states:

> Incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'int' with an
>   expression of type 'NSString *'

```
- (IBAction)Button:(id)sender 
{
  int x = TramNumber.text;
  if (x < 9)
  {
     Tramresult.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"lol"];
  }
  else
  {
    NSLog (@"x is less than 9!");
  }
}
@end
```

Please help. I am on iOS and running xCode 5.1.1 if that helps.

Comment: I suggest you use `NSInteger` and not `int`. `int` 32 bit and `NSInteger` a typedef for the systems native bit size, so 64 on 63 bits CPU en 32 on 32 bits systems.

Comment: Trivially reproducible: `int x = (NSString*)nil;` So *why* does the compiler warn about that?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You are representing `NSString` value wrong.

Use this code sample to solve your problem:

```
int x = [TramNumber.text intValue];
```

To represent int value from your textfield.

Answer (score 10):

```
int x = [TramNumber.text intValue];
```

You just need to convert NSString to int.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign text as an integer. 
You should cast NSString to int like this:

```
int x = [TramNumber.text intValue];
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try this:

```
NSString *code = dic[@"code"];
int statusCode = [code intValue];

NSLog(@"%d",statusCode);

if(statusCode==1)//........cont...
```